# Fitting autoregressive models to EEG timeseries

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

So I read that it is possible to fit AR models to EEG data and then use the AR coefficients as features for clustering or classifying data : e.g. Mohammadi et al, *Person identification by using AR model for EEG signals*, 2006.

As a quality control step, and as an aid for explanation, I wanted to visually see the type of timeseries produced/simulated by the fitted model. This would also allow me to show the prototype model if I was doing K means or something for classification.

However, all I seem to be able to produce is noise!

Any steps towards getting towards what I want would be more than welcome.

```
section1 = data[88000:91800]
section2 = data[0:8000]
section3 = data[143500:166000]

section1 -= np.mean(section1)
section2 -= np.mean(section2)
section3 -= np.mean(section3)
```

When plotted:
[image]

```
maxOrder = 20
model_one = AR(section1).fit(maxOrder, ic = 'aic', trend = 'nc') 
model_two = AR(section2).fit(maxOrder, ic = 'aic', trend = 'nc') 
model_three = AR(section3).fit(maxOrder, ic = 'aic', trend = 'nc') 

fake1 = arma_generate_sample(model_one.params,[1],1000, sigma = 1)
fake2 = arma_generate_sample(model_two.params,[1],1000,sigma = 1)
fake3 = arma_generate_sample(model_three.params,[1],1000,sigma = 1)

ax1.plot(fake1)
ax2.plot(fake2)
ax3.plot(fake3)
```

[image]

Comment: The main problem is that the plots don't look like a AR with symmetric, Gaussian noise. The middle plot and the last plot have large negative shocks. Somewhat similar patterns are modeled in finance with asymmetric heavy tailed shock distributions. Also with this high frequency data 20 lags might be too short.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes that makes sense, AR with symmetric noise shouldn't model the two bottom traces that well - I'm a bit confused as to how EEG signals such as these might be modelled with AR, if they indeed are. If i use a higher lag number the model starts oscillating as prediction time increases. Do you know of any good (simple) resources explaining asymmetric heavy tailed shock distributions, or how to fit/code them?

Answer (score 3):

The standard simplest more-or-less-true thing to say about EEG data is that it has a 1/f or "pink" distribution. An interesting thing about 1/f signals is that they are non-stationary, and cannot be correctly modelled by an ARMA process of any order. (1/f means that low frequency fluctuations are arbitrarily large, which means that arbitrarily far apart points remain correlated, and the more data you have, the further apart the correlations you can detect -- the ACF never converges to anything finite. Also, it's important to realize that spectral content and ARMA-like processes are super super related, because a signal's auto-correlation function totally determines its spectral distribution, and vice-versa -- the two functions are Fourier transforms of each other.)

So basically this means that anything you do using basic time series statistics is going to be a huge theory-violating hack. It doesn't mean it won't work in practice to produce some useful classification features, but calibrate your expectations accordingly... it might well be that the results you're getting are exactly the same as Mohammadi et al got, and they just didn't didn't bother to do any checking/reporting of goodness of fit.

There are ways to model 1/f noise directly, via wavelets or ARIMA processes.

Depending on your data, you may also need to worry about deviations from the simple 1/f distribution: stuff like alpha (which produces a substantial bump in the spectral distribution at 10 Hz), artifacts like muscle noise, electrical line noise, and heart beat (which also cause substantial deviations from the simple 1/f spectrum -- muscle in particular produces very distinctive broad-band ~whitish noise), and eye blinks (which produce huge impulse deviations that aren't going to be well-modelled by any technique that assumes stationarity or works in the frequency domain).

There's more discussion (with references) of these issues in section 5.3 of [my thesis](http://vorpus.org/papers/smith-2011-phd-thesis.pdf), though in the context of doing ERP-like analyses rather than machine learning.

Comment: Oh right, and those "downward shocks" in particular look like they *might* be heart beats to me (though I'm not nearly as expert at this stuff as some people). You might be able to separate them out with ICA or similar. It's definitely something weird going on; only the first of your three sample signals looks like clean EEG to me.

Comment: I am not sure if the data is scalp EEG or hippocampal field potentials. In the latter case the upper trace would be theta waves and the middle trace would be sharp-waves and ripples. If it is scalp EEG the upper trace would be alpha waves and the middle trace sleep spindles. It is not heart beat artifacts. They all look like clean recordings, depending on the state of the brain (e.g. REM sleep vs. slow-wave sleep).

Comment: A thing to note is that the ripples (200 Hz sigals produced by synchronous bursting neurons) follows immediately after the spike events. This is an indication they are population spike events and not ECG, EMG or EOG artifacts. If it was external noise it would not be time-locked to the ripples.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes sense -- I've only worked with awake behaving data myself.

Comment: Yes, these are actually field potentials, but they look similar to seizure events recorded by a single EEG channel so I didn't mention it. Sorry if this confused things. The top trace is baseline, middle just before seizure, and bottom seizure. So do you think an ARIMA might fit this better? Then I could classify based on the ARIMA parameters?